# mysql create table with mix column static and dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am having problem creating table with dynamic column from foreach results.

Code on preparing column:

```
$fields = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT goal_id FROM wpgetyp_goalsettings WHERE goaltype IN('daily','weekly') AND user_id='$current_user->ID'");
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $cfield = "field_$field->goal_id int(5) NOT NULL,";
}
```

Results:

```
field_1 int(5) NOT NULL,field_2 int(5) NOT NULL,field_3 int(5) NOT NULL,field_4 int(5) NOT NULL,field_5 int(5) NOT NULL,
```

Code to create table:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'user_'.$current_user->ID;
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
     //table not in database. Create new table
     $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

     $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
          id int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
          user_id varchar(15) NOT NULL,
          goals_type varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          goals_date date NOT NULL,
          start_time time NOT NULL,
          end_time time NOT NULL,
          $cfield
          lead_type varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          entry_date timestamp
     ) $charset_collate;";
     require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
     dbDelta( $sql );
}
else{
}
```

Take note on `$cfield`. It will only write the last result when creating the table. Only `field_5` will include during table creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting each result with a new value. Instead you need to concatenate all those values:

```
$fields = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT goal_id FROM wpgetyp_goalsettings WHERE goaltype IN('daily','weekly') AND user_id='$current_user->ID'");
$cfield = "";

foreach ($fields as $field) {
    // Long way of string concatenation
    $cfield = $cfield . "field_$field->goal_id int(5) NOT NULL, ";
    // Short way, mentioned by @FrankerZ in the comments (chose one)
    // $cfield .= "field_$field->goal_id int(5) NOT NULL, ";
}
```

Comment: You can simply use `$cfield .= "..."`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to accomplish this:

```
$cfield = implode(
    ', ',
    array_map(function($field) {
        return "field_$field->goal_id int(5) NOT NULL";
    }, $fields)
);

echo $cfield;
```

The above block also takes care of the dangling `,` at the end. See [this output](https://3v4l.org/AAK6G) for an example.